# Splitting a Full Name into First and Last Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of customer whose name is given as a full name.
I want to create a function that takes the full name as parameter and returns the first and last name separately. If this is not possible I can have two separate functions one that returns the first name and the other that returns the last name. The full name list contains names that have a maximum of three words.
What I want is this:-

- When a full name is composed of two words. The first one should be
  the name and the second one should be the last name.
- When a full name is composed of three words. The first and middle words should   be the first name while the third word should be the last name.

Example:-

```
**Full Name**    
John Paul White    
Peter Smith    
Ann Marie Brown    
Jack Black    
Sam Olaf Turner
```

Result:-

```
**First Name    Last Name**    
John Paul     White    
Peter         Smith      
Ann Marie     Brown    
Jack          Black    
Sam Olaf      Turner
```

I have search and found solutions that are not working as intended and would like some advice.

Comment: This requirement is problematic. e.g. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-barrelled_name  and http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: As long as you're aware that these rules will split the name into two parts, not necessarily into "first name" and "last name", this is simply about finding and picking the right space and then split the string in two. If your requirement is to pick the right space to find the right first name and last name, boy oh boy are you in for a scope-creep surprise. Parsing names into correct parts is an impossible task because exactly what one person considers his first and last name might not be what another one would, even if they have the same "full name" when put together.

Comment: The logical choice should've been to have distinct fields for first, middle, last, etc. and let the person having the name decide what goes where.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keeping it short and simple

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(Fullname varchar(40))
INSERT @t VALUES('John Paul White'),('Peter Smith'),('Thomas')

SELECT
  LEFT(Fullname, LEN(Fullname) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(FullName))) FirstName,
  STUFF(RIGHT(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(FullName))),1,1,'') LastName
FROM
  @t
```

Result:

```
FirstName  LastName
John Paul  White
Peter      Smith
Thomas     NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are *certain* that your names will only ever be two or three words, with single spaces, then we can rely on the base string functions to extract the first and last name components.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN LEN(col) = LEN(REPLACE(col, ' ', '')) + 2
         THEN SUBSTRING(col, 1,
                        CHARINDEX(' ', col, CHARINDEX(' ', col) + 1) - 1)
         ELSE SUBSTRING(col, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', col) - 1)
    END AS first,
    CASE WHEN LEN(col) = LEN(REPLACE(col, ' ', '')) + 2
         THEN SUBSTRING(col,
                        CHARINDEX(' ', col, CHARINDEX(' ', col) + 1) + 1,
                        LEN(col) - CHARINDEX(' ', col, CHARINDEX(' ', col)))
         ELSE SUBSTRING(col,
                        CHARINDEX(' ', col) + 1,
                        LEN(col) - CHARINDEX(' ', col))
    END AS last
FROM yourTable;
```

Yuck, but it seems to work.  My feeling is that you should fix your data model at some point.  A more ideal place to scrub your name data would be outside the database, e.g. in Java.  Or, better yet, fix the source of your data such that you record proper first and last names from the very beginning.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 1):

Another option (just for fun) is to use a little XML in concert with an CROSS APPLY

**Example**

```
Select FirstName = ltrim(reverse(concat(Pos2,' ',Pos3,' ',Pos4,' ',Pos5)))
      ,LastName  = reverse(Pos1)
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos5 = xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace(reverse(A.[Full Name]),' ','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) XMLData
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
FirstName               LastName
John Paul               White
Peter                   Smith
Ann Marie               Brown
Jack                    Black
Sam Olaf                Turner
                        Cher
Sally Anne Bella Donna  Baxter
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do two things at once...I won't solve for you, but here's the direction I'd take:

1) Check this out for string splitting: https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/split-string-to-table-using-transact-sql.html. This will allow you to parse the name into a temp table and you can perform your logic on it to create names based on your rules

2) Create this as a table-valued function so that you can return a single row of parsed FirstName, LastName from your parameter. That way you can join to it and include in your results

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried by Using PARSENAME Function?

The last method in splitting a full name into its corresponding first name and last name is the use of the PARSENAME string function, as can be seen from the following script:

```
    DECLARE @FullName VARCHAR(100)
    SET @FullName = 'John White Doe'

    SELECT CONCAT(PARSENAME(REPLACE(@FullName, ' ', '.'), 3),' ',PARSENAME(REPLACE(@FullName, ' ', '.'), 2)) AS [FirstName],
  PARSENAME(REPLACE(@FullName, ' ', '.'), 1) AS [LastName]
```

For more information, Goto this [Site](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/split-name.aspx) 
[image]

This is the output..

[image]

Comment: That returns "Paul" and "White" and loses the "John". Just in case anyone gets the wrong impression `PARSENAME`  is for parsing dot delimited object names such as `MyDB.dbo.MyTable` - not human names.

Comment: @MartinSmith That function is future-proof, once we run out of social security numbers everybodys name is going to be based on a domain-spaces dot-based naming system. My name will be norway.telemark.porsgrunn.lasse.vågsæther.karlsen and then the function will be just perfect! Until we start colonizing planets that is. And forget about moving, ever.

Comment: Sorry, [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith) Now I have corrected that thing. You can check it on this [SQL server compiler](http://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler)

Comment: The script is not correct for input `@FullName = 'John White'`

Answer (score 0):

Make it a table-valued function.

see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165.aspx) for an example

And this is the code you need to create your function. Basically you just need to split your **LastName**

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.ufnParseName', N'TF') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.ufnParseName;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufnParseName(@FullName VARCHAR(300))
RETURNS @retParseName TABLE 
(
-- Columns returned by the function    
FirstName nvarchar(150) NULL,  
LastName nvarchar(50) NULL
)
AS 
-- Returns the spliced last name.
BEGIN

     DECLARE 
        @FirstName nvarchar(250),
        @LastName nvarchar(250);
    -- Get common contact information

    SELECT @LastName = RTRIM(RIGHT(@FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@FullName)) - 1));
    SELECT @FirstName = LTRIM(RTRIM(Replace(@FullName, @LastName, '')))

     INSERT @retParseName
        SELECT @FirstName, @LastName;

    RETURN;
END
```

You can run as `SELECT * FROM dbo.ufnParseName('M J K');`

#### Why Table-Valued-Function

You can get rid off the duplication of your sql query and achieve DRY

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query. It is written as per your requirement and it only handles full_name with 2 or 3 parts in it.

```
;WITH cte AS(
    SELECT full_name, (LEN(full_name) - LEN(REPLACE(full_name, ' ', '')) + 1) AS size FROM @temp
    )

SELECT FirstName = 
    CASE 
        WHEN size=3 THEN PARSENAME(REPLACE(full_name, ' ', '.'), 3) + ' ' + PARSENAME(REPLACE(full_name, ' ', '.'), 2)
        ELSE PARSENAME(REPLACE(full_name, ' ', '.'), 2)
    END,
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(full_name, ' ', '.'), 1) AS LastName
FROM cte
```

Comment: This doesn't seem more simple than my answer. It does handle 1 part names as well, putting the 1 part in last name

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Yes, your's one is more simple. Sorry haven't seen your's one before submitting my one.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was the following:

```
SUBSTR(Full_Name,1,(LOCATE(Full_Name, ' '))) AS FIRSTTNAME,
SUBSTR(Full_Name,(LOCATE(Full_Name, ' ')+1)) AS LASTNAME
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).